# Entity Framework Code First Query with Dynamic Table Name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use entity framework code first.Is it possible to give table name dynamically in query phase.I want to pass table name to mymethod and set table name dynamically.

I can use like this.

```
[Table("MY_MESSAGE", Schema = "MySchema")]
   public class MyMessage
   {
       [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
       public string REQUESTID { get; set; }
       public string BAG { get; set; }
}


 public DbSet<MyMessagee> SET_TBL_MYMESSAGE { get; set; }

public MyMessage GetMessageByRequestID(string TableName, string RequestID)
        {
            using (HandlerDatabaseContext dbContext = HandlerDatabaseContext.CreateContext())
            {
                var handlerQuery = from table in dbContext.SET_TBL_MYMESSAGE
                                           where table.REQUESTID == RequestID
                                           select table;

                ...
}
```

Comment: You are obviously not using EF Code first.
Entity Framework **Code First** means that you create the database from the classes you defined in your code.
Why do you need to pass the table name on the fly? Are you sure you should use an ORM for this?